# image stored as .tmp in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to upload an image but when i check my public folder the image has a different name and a .tmp extension :

```
public function store_company(Request $request)
{
      $request->validate([
          'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpg,png,jpeg|max:3048'
      ]);

      $name = $request->RS;
      $name = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $name);

      $NewLogoName = time() . 'lo-go-' . $name . '.' . $request->image->extension();
      $path = $request->image->move(public_path('assets/images' , $NewLogoName));


      $company = new entreprise;

      $company->RS = $request->RS;
      $company->adresse = $request->adresse;
      $company->Fax = $request->Fax;
      $company->Tel1 = $request->Tel1;
      $company->Tel2 = $request->Tel2;
      $company->mail = $request->mail;
      $company->Logo = $NewLogoName;

      $company->save();

      return redirect('/Dashboard');

}
```

please any idea how to solve this !

Comment: I don't think move() function creates an image in the target folder. As far as I know, you need to create the image by GD library or Intervention Image.

Comment: You want to use the [`store`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#file-uploads) method rather than move. There is also a [`storeAs`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#specifying-a-file-name) for specifying a name.

Comment: @Unflux when i use the store method i get this error " Impossible to create the root directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\amarrakech\storage\app\C:/xampp/htdocs/amarrakech/public/assets/images"."

Comment: @Unflux and when i use the storeAs method i get another error " Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile::storeAs() "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You moved the temporary file (uploaded file) from the tmp folder to the public folder. since you did not provide a name it kept the tmp filename.

in `move()` the second parameter is the new file name and the first one is just the path.

change it to

```
$path = $request->image->move(public_path('assets/images'), $NewLogoName);
```

Comment: isn't that exactly what i wrote !!

Comment: @N96S oh i just realized what's the difference ... and it worked thank you so much